# Java Remote desktop administration

Tags: java

I m currently working on my project of remote desktop administration. I m using robot class to capture images and send over network. It works well but bit slower.

Because all the time we need to captuure and send image its too costly. Is it possible to detect only a portion of screen which is changed and send only that portion?

Please any one guide me on this. Thank you!!!

Comment: (Any reason why an existing [proven] tool isn't being used?)

Answer (score 2):

The keyword you're looking for (in order to be able to look this up and figure the solution yourself) is **[dirty rectangles](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DirtyRectangles)**.

[You can look into some code here](http://amazonsystems.blogspot.com/2009/01/dirty.html).

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this awhile back, and the image capture is implemented particularly inefficiently. I don't recall the specific detail, but it was pretty bad the way they did it. I felt, at the time, that the only way to do it better would be to implement it in JNI. Which you could use JNA to shortcut.

I don't know if any platform's screen capture routines will allow only changed sections to be sent, but you could implement a decent image diff; although that could get expensive too. You would really need to measure whats going on to see if it works for you.